# How does this L1 regularization derivation follow? (Proof it makes sparse models)

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, normed-spaces, machine-learning, regularization

I'm reading the "Deep Learning"(Goodfellow et al, 2016) book and on pages 231-232(you can check them [here](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/regularization.html)) they show a very unique proof how L1 regularization makes model sparse. You can skip to the last two expressions for the actual question, but some context if you want it:

The regularized objetive function $\tilde{J}(\boldsymbol{w} ; \boldsymbol{X}, \boldsymbol{y})$ is given by:
$$ \tilde{J}(\boldsymbol{w} ; \boldsymbol{X}, \boldsymbol{y})=\alpha\|\boldsymbol{w}\|_{1}+J(\boldsymbol{w} ; \boldsymbol{X}, \boldsymbol{y})$$
where $\boldsymbol{w}$ is the parameter vector and $\boldsymbol{X}, \boldsymbol{y}$ are the design matrix(inputs) and the outputs of the model, respectively.

If we make a second order Taylor series approximation of the unregularized loss function of our model, which we will assume it is a linear model to ensure it has a clean analytical solution we have
$$\hat{J}(\boldsymbol{\theta})=J\left(\boldsymbol{w}^{*}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(\boldsymbol{w}-\boldsymbol{w}^{*}\right)^{\top} \boldsymbol{H}\left(\boldsymbol{w}-\boldsymbol{w}^{*}\right)$$
where $\boldsymbol{H}$ is the Hessian matrix of $J$ with respect to $\boldsymbol{w}$ evaluated at $\boldsymbol{w}^{*}$ and there is no ﬁrst-order term in this quadratic approximation because $\boldsymbol{w}^{*}$ is deﬁned to be a minimum.

The minimum of $\hat{J}$ occurs where its gradient
$$\nabla_{\boldsymbol{w}} \hat{J}(\boldsymbol{w})=\boldsymbol{H}\left(\boldsymbol{w}-\boldsymbol{w}^{*}\right)$$

If we make the further assumption that the Hessian is diagonal $\boldsymbol{H}=\operatorname{diag}\left(\left[H_{1,1}, \ldots, H_{n, n}\right]\right), $ where each $ H_{i, i}>0$ (more details on the book), we have that our quadratic approximation of the L1 regularized objective function decomposes into a sum over the parameters:
$$\hat{J}(\boldsymbol{w} ; \boldsymbol{X}, \boldsymbol{y})=J\left(\boldsymbol{w}^{*} ; \boldsymbol{X}, \boldsymbol{y}\right)+\sum_{i}\left[\frac{1}{2} H_{i, i}\left(\boldsymbol{w}_{i}-\boldsymbol{w}_{i}^{*}\right)^{2}+\alpha\left|w_{i}\right|\right]$$

Then they say (**and this is where I don't see how they did it, specifically that max function**)

> The problem of minimizing this approximate cost function has an analytical solution(for each dimension i), with the following form:
>   $$w_{i}=\operatorname{sign}\left(w_{i}^{*}\right) \max \left\{\left|w_{i}^{*}\right|-\frac{\alpha}{H_{i, i}}, 0\right\}$$

How did they get that expression? I've reached a similar one, but without that max function...

For further insights, please refer to the book.

Comment: Why is the sign being applied to $w_i^*$ rather than $w_i$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeking to minimize $g(w_i) := \frac{1}{2} H_{ii} (w_i - w^*_i)^2 + \alpha |w_i|$.

---

Approach using the theory of [subdifferentials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subderivative#Properties):

Let $f(x) = |x|$. The minimizer $\hat{w}_i$ must satisfy
$$0 \in \partial g(\hat{w}_i) = H_{ii}(\hat{w}_i - w^*_i) + \alpha \partial f(\hat{w}_i)$$
where $$\partial f(x) = \begin{cases}\{1\} & x > 0 \\ [-1, 1] & x = 0 \\ \{-1\} & x < 0\end{cases}$$
We can rearrange the above expression $0 \in \partial g(\hat{w}_i)$ as
\begin{align}
-\frac{H_{ii}}{\alpha} (\hat{w}_i - w_i^*)  \in \begin{cases}\{1\} & \hat{w}_i > 0 \\ [-1, 1] & \hat{w}_i = 0 \\ \{-1\}  & \hat{w}_i < 0\end{cases}
\end{align}
You can check that the given solution satisfies this condition by checking the various cases of what $w^*_i$ is.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't see how your answer ressembles the expression above. Could you further clarify please? And secondly, in your last expression, where did that minus come from? Why is the derivative of f(x) not adding anymore? I understood the subderivative of f(x) but I can't still wrap my head around about the rest. Thank you for the answer and the reference.

Comment: I found [this document](https://people.seas.harvard.edu/~yaron/AM221-S16/sections/sec6.pdf) and in proposition 6 they show an equivalent problem and solution. It took me a while but I finally see how they get that expression and how they transform it in the book to that single line. Thank you for the insights. Still, I think it would be great if you could clarify further for future readers.

Comment: @PHAN can you elaborate how you related Proposition 6 from the linked notes to the desired expression, I'm still not really grasping this problem.